# calculate rank by positive and negative numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I have a table with 2 columns:

`monthly_sales, quality_score`

I would like to order these by some function of **high** `monthly_sales` and **lowest** `quality_score`.

If my data is:

```
id, monthly_sales, quality_score
1,  10000,        30
2,  100,          10
3,  20000,        20
4,  100000,       10
5,  100000,       90
6,  20000,        90
7,  200,          20
```

Would like to see something like:

```
id, monthly_sales, quality_score
4,  100000,       10
3,  20000,        20
1,  10000,        30
5,  100000,       90
6,  20000,        90
2,  100,          10
7,  200,          20
```

I know that I **do not want** to `ORDER BY quality_score ASC, monthly_sales DESC` because the two items on bottom **should be on the bottom**. Need to kinda weight the `monthly_sales` by the inverse of quality score

Comment: Maybe I'm reading your question wrong...but if "I would like to order these by some function of high monthly_sales and lowest quality_score." is the question, then I believe "write some function that calculates a score based on monhly_sales and lowest quality and order by that function" is the answer.  Can't really help you further without expanding details on "some function"  (if you need help creating a function that takes in 2 variables as monthly_sales and quality_score and spits out some value you can order by, let me know)

Comment: perhaps defining how the relationship function should look like would help. else the expected result is impossible with the given data.

Comment: order by monthly_sales / quality_score kinda works, but id 1 and 5 would be a different order...I think?

Comment: hmmmm @Twelfth I am capable of ordering by a number... to answer your comment yes i need help creating a weighted average thing in SQL

Comment: started a comment, realized it may as well be an answer.  You will need to come up with your own ranking formula, but a custom function and ordering by it is pretty straight forward.  Tons of documentation and examples avail online too.

Answer (score 1):

@BlairAnderson - it's actually decently simple.  Not sure on your postgres version, but 9.1 function create documentation here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html

```
 create function rank_for_order (sales int, score int) returns integer as 
 begin
    return sales / score^2 
     --or any other calc for this here
 end;
```

then in your query, you can

```
order by rank_for_order(monthly_sales,quality_score)
```

or to test

```
select  rank_for_order(monthly_sales,quality_score) from table
```

Comment: thank you! can you explain why you chose example function `sales / score^2`? I think thats more along the lines of what i'm trying to understand. How to rank them accurately. OP was more of a numbers question than SQL question but i wasn't sure if SQL had something built-in related to math.

Comment: @BlairAnderson - I hate to say it, but I pretty randomly came up with that in an attempt to resolve "1,  10000,        30 vs 5,  100000,       90".  Trial and error your formula until you have something you like...not much for standardization out there for custom ordering.  Honestly, there is no need for the function, you could simply have this math in the order by clause just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can come pretty close to your ordering using:

```
order by monthly_sales / quality_score
```

I can reproduce the ordering using:

```
order by monthly_sales / power(quality_score, 2.4)
```

Values between 2.1 and 2.4 appear to work.

That doesn't seem like an incredibly natural or useful way of defining an ordering, however.

Comment: This answer is pretty awesome, can you explain why it works?

Comment: @BlairAnderson . . . Because that is how the numbers in your example work.  The choice of exponent is arbitrary, except that it orders the values as you specify.